# Duvida com o Notepad++

Tags: lua, editor-de-texto, notepad++

Como faço para o Notepad++ fazer por exemplo:

```
function test()
    var=true
end
```

em vez de

```
function test()
var=true
end
```

desculpe não sei como se chama essa ação,mas sempre quando eu inicio uma função ou algo do tipo,ele adiciona 4 espaços até que eu insira `end`.

Comment: Acho que oque você procura é indentação  de código, nem todos editores vem com suporte para todas as linguagens. Mas com certeza tem um plugin pra isso pro notepad++.

Comment: Para acrescentar, o Sublime Text tem indentação automática por padrão. Existe um síntaxe de Lua melhor que a padrão do S.T., GModLua. Talvez S.T.  caiba melhor como um editor. Até agora o único mais completo em questão de controle das teclas Home, End, e Tab, e a seleção de texto é completa tbm. Agora falta deixar melhor a síntaxe do Lua.